# React components not showing

Tags: reactjs

Hello I am programming chess board but components aren't visible.
I cannot see those div's "{square.id}" in this line

```
const horizontalLine = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"];
const verticalLine = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"];
const squares = [verticalLine.map((verticals) => (
  horizontalLine.map((horizontals) => (
    {
      id: `${verticals+horizontals}`,
      ver: `${verticals}`,
      hor: `${horizontals}`
    }
  ))
))];

function App() {

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {squares.map((square) => (
        <div id={square.id} key={square.id}>{square.id}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Try adding some style (such as height, width, and color etc.)

Answer (score 2):

> React components not showing

`squares` is an array of arrays of arrays and you are actually using only one loop. I would suggest to get rid of one wrapping array and add an additional inner loop.

```
const horizontalLine = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"];
const verticalLine = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"];
const squares = verticalLine.map((verticals) => ( // remove wrapping array
  horizontalLine.map((horizontals) => (
    {
      id: `${verticals+horizontals}`,
      ver: `${verticals}`,
      hor: `${horizontals}`
    }
  ))
));

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {squares.map((square) => (
        square.map((innerSquare) => ( // additional loop
           <div id={innerSquare.id} key={innerSquare.id}>{innerSquare.id}</div>
        ))
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-dawn-q5jjpm?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Your `squares` object is an array with single element which is 8x8 2-dimensional matrix. When rendering the `squares` matrix, you are looping through only that single element. You need to access to first element `squares` array and then loop through both rows and then columns:

```js
{squares[0].map((row) => (
  row.map((square) => (
    <div id={square.id} key={square.id}>{square.id}</div>
  )
)))}
```